# How to get value in Js of other field that is passed to widget? Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I created a widget which fills some fields automatically.  Basically I am checking some values from google maps geolocate and filling other fields depending on what those values are. Turned out I need to check one value that is already in my form. What happens at the moment I get only value that was saved before and if it changes I still get the old value. My question if how to get that value real-time?

My code is something like this:

```
var gmap_autocomplete = form_common.AbstractField.extend({

// functions such as start, init, on_ready...
setFields : function (fieldName, fieldValue) {
       var not_vat_payer = this.view.datarecord[this.node.attrs.check_not_vat]);

       // Here I get the value that I want of previous form save
       // for example if value was true, I came here and triggered this
      //widget I will get value true, but if I change it to false
      // I will still get true value of previous save

}

});
```

My field with widget looks like this:

```
<field name="not_vat2"/>
<field name="autocomplete" class="autoc" widget="gmap_autocomplete" street="street"
                                   city="city" zip="zip" country_id="country_id" lang="lang" invoice_lang="invoice_lang"
                                    property_account_payable_id="property_account_payable_id"
                                    property_account_receivable_id="property_account_receivable_id"
                                    check_not_vat="not_vat2"/>
```

Comment: you need to call python method from js code whenever you update value in javascript. do you know how to do that?

Comment: That's weird actually I was thinking the same and I tried to do something like that, but it didn't work, I don't know how to do it correctly.  I did something like:

Comment: new Model('res.parnter')
                .call("get_vat", [])
                .done(function (record) {
                    console.log(record)
                })
            }

Comment: ok let me give some code suggestions because that is possible

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution which is really simple:
This will return field value which is in view no matter its stored in db or not.

```
   this.field_manager.get_field_value('field_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

**exmple.js**

Make changes something like..

```
var model_obj = new Model('model.name');
var gmap_autocomplete = form_common.AbstractField.extend({

// functions such as start, init, on_ready...
setFields : function (fieldName, fieldValue) {
       var not_vat_payer = this.view.datarecord[this.node.attrs.check_not_vat]);
       new_val = false;
       model_obj.call('method_name',[new_val]).then(function(result){});

}

});
```

**example.py**

```
@api.model
def method_name(self,new_val):
    //write code for change field value
```

Comment: My checkbox is set to True. When I call function      def get_not_vat(self):
        print self.not_vat2
        return self.not_vat2, it return True when its called in pyhhon and it always return false when called from JS, any idea why?

Comment: because python function returns value from database and javascript function return current value from checkbox. you need to write values in database using python and set the same value in check box by get value from python function in javascript.

Comment: Well Javascrip also return value from database that's the problem. If you change it it will still get the value from database. And Python funcion no mater what value is in db, return False. I think that actual value is saved somewhere in cache, I just need to reach it somehow.

Comment: As I mentioned I don't even need to call python function to get value from database. I get it with this: this.view.datarecord[this.node.attrs.check_not_vat]); But I need to get value from field if it's changed and not saved yet, that was my question. Sorry If I didn't ask it correctly :/

Comment: yes I know you get the value from this.view.datarecord[this.node.attrs.check_not_vat]) here but check_not_vat get value from not_vat2 and that's python field so it gets value from database .. Do you get me now?